# Microsoft365 VBE is oversized

Tags: vba

I can not use VBA with my Office365. I'm using a high resolution laptop and an external monitor. There wasn't any problem before.. but for a few weeks my microsoft365 (office, excel, word, outlook, .. ) VBA IDE has a great problem. VBA application window is oversized; as attached image.VBA IDE Screen - the text File is the File menu it self

[image: Oversized VBE]

I tried every resolution and scale options for both display devices but nothing changed, I made online repair of microsoft365 two times but it did not fix anything. I replaced the dll files in the C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA7.1 folder but it did not solve the problem. Other applications that use activeX do not have the same problem. But Form.Move event does not work properly since then. (I think a windows system update caused this problem) So I can not make a new installation of windows, I am waiting for the future main update of win 11.

Windows 11 Pro - 22H2 - 22621.963 - Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22638.1000.0

I hope that someone will guide me to solve the problem. Thanks.

Online repair of Microsoft365

Comment: Try the steps described on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26811218/11443568

Comment: Thanks. I tried the steps. I deleted the Common folder in the registry. It is created again when I restart and switch to Excel VBE but the problem remains the same. I exported related registry settings from a working pc and import them to my win pc.. nothing really happened. An oversized File menu is still expanding to all UI of VBE.